# UIWebView won't load(Error -999)

Tags: ios, objective-c, error-handling, uiwebview

When I start loading my UIWebView it gives me this error:

```
2015-06-12 10:24:08.768 App[7034:692175] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)" UserInfo=0x165f3950 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://google.com/, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://google.com/}
```

And it never finishes loading. The weird part is: When I execute it on the simulator it works just fine. Also when I reload the webview by hand it works fine as well.

Therefore it means the URL and it's parameters are just fine(https://google.com/ is not the actual URL).

Online I found this workaround:

```
if([error code] == NSURLErrorCancelled){
        return;
    }else{
        //Actual error handling
}
```

This does get called, but doesn't solve the issue

EDIT: 
_

```
webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.infoView.frame.size.width, self.infoView.frame.size.height)];
    [self.infoView addSubview:_webView];
    [_webView setHidden:YES];
    _webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
    _webView.delegate = self;
    _webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    _webView.scrollView.bounces = NO;
    [_webView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [_webView addSubview:invisView];
    [_webView loadRequest:[self getRequest]];
```

Comment: Can you please post your UIWebView initialization code?

Comment: What is `[self getRequest]`?

Comment: That is a function that creates the NSURLRequest and adds the necessary parameters and session info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in iOS with HTTPS requests. A workaround for me was redoing the request when the error is given. The second time the request seemed to load fine and it works perfectly now.

Comment: This does not really answer the question.  Can you provide more detail about how you fixed the request?